# Help regarding deployment in Polygon Matic Testnet

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, polygon

I am using truffle (`Truffle v5.1.65 - a development framework for Ethereum`) for my smartcontracts deployment.

My `truffle-config.js` has network setting for `matic` as:

```
  //https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/v1/<key>
    //https://matic-testnet-archive-rpc.bwarelabs.com/
    //https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key>
    matic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://matic-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com`),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      // gasPrice: 10000000,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
```

The commented 3 lines are different rpc url that I am currently trying to deploy but none of them actual worked for me.

Issues are sometimes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this config for Matic Network

```
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/`),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    }
```