# Can't deploy contracts on Mumbai

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-deployment

I'm trying to deploy one smart contract on Mumbai with truffle but It gives me this error

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

/Users/danielevl/projects/mnm/fdv/fdv2/smart-contracts/node_modules/eth-block- 
tracker/src/polling.js:51
    const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                   ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/Users/danielevl/projects/mnm/fdv/fdv2/smart-contracts/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: [Object] }
}
} {
   code: -32603,
   message: 'Socket connection timeout',
   data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Socket connection timeout',
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: [Object] }
}
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
```

I've tried to deploy following the [Polygon wiki](https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/tools/ethereum/truffle/#configuring-the-smart-contract) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102302/unable-to-connect-to-polygon-mumbai-test-network-using-truffle) question and, as an alternative, using Infura with a personal API KEY but nothing works.

Sometime It starts to deploy the Migration contract and then gives me a timeout error, or Socket Connection Error.

Thank you

Comment: It seems to be a connection issue. Try testing with a different RPC provider.

Comment: I've tried to deploy with Hardhat and I've been able to deploy, so the problem is not the RPC provider